# Can :checked selector affect a div with which has no relation?

Tags: html, css, menu, navigation, slidetoggle

Some of my issues was trying to follow some tutorials about off-screen navigation menu but they didn't quite fit my requirements. 
Here is one [example](http://codepen.io/SitePoint/pen/uIemr/)

What I am trying to accomplish here is kinda difficult and I can't find the answer. What I want is to press on the label and toggle the sidebar. Most of the tutorials show that **but only when these two are directly related**.

```
<div class="header">
   <ul>
      <li>Menu1</li>
      <li>Menu2</li>
      <li>Menu3</li>
      <li>
          <input type="checkbox" class="sidebar__toggle" id="sidebar__toggle">
          <label for="sidebar__toggle">More info</label>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
<div class="content">
    ...rest of code here...
</div>
<div class="sidebar">
    ...sidebar code here...
</div>
```

And css(I'll be omitting the rest for the sake of simplicity):

```
.sidebar__toggle:checked  ~ .sidebar {
    background-color: pink;
}
```

As I followed the various tutorials on the web, this was the method if they we're related somehow, but mine(or THE one I need) actually is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the checkbox anywhere you want as long as the label points to its `id` using the `for` attribute.  I put it in front of `.sidebar` below:

```css
.sidebar__toggle:checked  ~ .sidebar {
    background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
   <ul>
      <li>Menu1</li>
      <li>Menu2</li>
      <li>Menu3</li>
      <li>
          <label for="sidebar__toggle">More info</label>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
<div class="content">
    ...rest of code here...
</div>
<input type="checkbox" class="sidebar__toggle" id="sidebar__toggle">
<div class="sidebar">
    ...sidebar code here...
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, had no idea this was possible!